# terraform create key/value only if defined

Tags: terraform

I am working on cloudwatch alarm that will differentiate targets having one or two dimensions. I've tried `try` but can't get it working. I am not sure if what I want to achieve is even possible.

here are the locals:

```
locals {
    dynamodb_table = {
        "table_1" = { type = "read", comparison = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", metric_name = "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits", period = "60", threshold = "60", evaluation_periods = "5", dimension_table = "TableName" },
        "table_2" = { type = "write", comparison = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", metric_name = "ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits",period = "60", threshold = "60", evaluation_periods = "5", dimension_table = "TableName", dimension_index = "GlobalSecondaryIndexName" }
   }
}
```

resource shortened for brevity:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dynamodb" {
...
  dimensions = {
    (each.value.dimension_table) = each.key
    try(each.value.dimension_index, {}) = "something"
  }
```

as you can see `dimension_index` exists only for one table and shouldn't be created if it doesn't exits in the locals to look like:

```
  dimensions = {
    TableName = "table_1"
  }
```

vs.

```
  dimensions = {
    TableName = "table_2"
    GlobalSecondaryIndexName = "something"
  }
```

in plan. I've tried the same with `count` but I was getting always `GlobalSecondaryIndexName = 0` which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Is your data structure fixed an unchangeable. To me this feels like poor design of the locals object thats causing the real issue here.

Comment: Each table (and there are more than two of it) has different alarm thresholds, periods, evaluations. How would you design it to not be poor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) to check if the key exists in the map, and build `dimensions` accordingly:

```
locals {
  dynamodb_table = {
    "table_1" = { type = "read", comparison = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", metric_name = "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits", period = "60", threshold = "60", evaluation_periods = "5", dimension_table = "TableName" },
    "table_2" = { type = "write", comparison = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", metric_name = "ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits", period = "60", threshold = "60", evaluation_periods = "5", dimension_table = "TableName", dimension_index = "GlobalSecondaryIndexName" }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dynamodb" {
  ...
  dimensions = lookup(each.value, "dimension_index", null) != null ? {
    "${each.value.dimension_table}" = each.key
    "${each.value.dimension_index}" = "something"
    } : {
    "${each.value.dimension_table}" = each.key
  }
}
```

```bash
$ terraform plan

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.dynamodb["table_1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dynamodb" {
      ...
      + dimensions                            = {
          + "TableName" = "table_1"
        }
      ...

  # aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.dynamodb["table_2"] will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dynamodb" {
      ...
      + dimensions                            = {
          + "GlobalSecondaryIndexName" = "something"
          + "TableName"                = "table_2"
        }
```

Comment: Worked, thank you very much.

Comment: I am still not a huge fan of this as it still feels a bit hacky and am sure the real issue is the data structure in the locals. However one recommendation I would make to reduce the code replication of the dimension table part is to use  a merge so you only write it once

Comment: something like this https://pastebin.com/UtNRTc28

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle , an alternative could certainly be building a third local variable which had similar logic ; using the merge approach would indeed be more concise, however I usually prefer readability when we're talking about such few numbers of lines of code